# Custom layout file destroys my Android application (No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value))

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to create ListView with customized layout elements. I found a sample layout from Internet. However, when I add it to my app it destroys everything. I get several errors, like

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with
> value '@id/textViewCapital').
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>
> Cannot resolve symbol R

Here is my layout file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp">
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFlag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/textViewCapital"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageViewFlag"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewFlag"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Country Name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCapital"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageViewFlag"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewFlag"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Country Capital"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I dont understand what is wrong with this code. I am new to Android Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:layout_above="@+id/textViewCapital"
```

For the `id` that you are using before defining it, you need to add `+` sign, because your component doesn't know that `id`, isn't defined yet.

Comment: It worked, thanks for very fast answer. That's strange that I've read a lot of tutorials, watched many videos but have never met someone mentioning this rule.

Comment: Another strange thing is generating so many errors from this simple issue by Android Studio.

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself. Learning is a process which requires time, patience and commitment. Just keep pushing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please add this:
android:layout_above="@+id/textViewCapital"

Instead of:
android:layout_above="@id/textViewCapital"

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

The resource id must be create before using the resource. You are using textViewCapital resource in textViewName as above view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="6dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewFlag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCapital"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewFlag"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewFlag"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Country Capital"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textViewCapital"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewFlag"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewFlag"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Country Name"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

HOpe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/textViewCapital"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageViewFlag"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewFlag"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Country Name"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

you have created is below that it has not been created that point of time

Try putting it down it will not have any issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFlag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCapital"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageViewFlag"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewFlag"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Country Capital"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/textViewCapital"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageViewFlag"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewFlag"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Country Name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

or try putting  `android:layout_above="@+id/textViewCapital"` as view is not created at that point you may use id of view which will be created later.